# Property of derivative of Dirac delta function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, distribution-theory

With reference to [Property of Dirac delta function in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56939/property-of-dirac-delta-function-in-mathbbrn), is there a similar formula for $\langle g^*\delta', f \rangle$ (or even $\langle g^*\delta^{(n)}, f \rangle$)? By similar I mean a representation by an integral over $g^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: I found Wagner's paper in Appl. Anal. 89 (2010), no. 8, 1183–1199. Maybe I should read that first.