# Integral transform with Dirac delta

Tags: integration, transformation, distribution-theory

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\delta$ denote the Dirac delta function.

How can I write the integral over $\mathbb{R}^n$ (on the left hand side) as an integral over $g^{-1}(0)$

$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(r) \delta(g(r))\ dr 
\ \ \ = \int\limits_{g^{-1}(0)} ?\ dr
$$

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56939/property-of-dirac-delta-function-in-mathbbrn

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
You can use
$$
\int{\rm f}\pars{\vec{r}}\delta\pars{{\rm g}\pars{\vec{r}}}\,\dd^{n}\vec{r}
=
\int{\rm f}\pars{\vec{r}}
\bracks{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic k{\rm g}\pars{\vec{r}}}
\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}}\dd^{n}\vec{r}
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd k \over 2\pi}\bracks{%
\int{\rm f}\pars{\vec{r}}\expo{\ic k{\rm g}\pars{\vec{r}}}\,\dd^{n}\vec{r}}
$$

ADDENDUM:

In some particular cases ( it depends on the particular form of ${\rm g}$ ), the Dirac delta $\delta\pars{{\rm g}\pars{\vec{r}}}$ can be reduced to a product of "more simple" Dirac delta's. For example, with $n = 3$ and spherical coordinates it's like
$$
\delta\pars{\vec{r}}
=
{1 \over r^{2}}\delta\pars{r}\delta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}\delta\pars{\phi}
$$

Comment: Maybe they can. But then what?

Comment: @Did $f$ and $g$ are known functions. It's reduced to a "technical problem".

Comment: @Did Thanks. You motivated the ADDENDUM.

Answer (score 0):

See Gelfand and Shilov "Generalized Functions, vol. 1" page 222.  The Delta Distribution with a function as its argument is discussed there.  On page 230 there is the following definition (with $k=1$):

$\delta(P,\phi) = \int_{P=0}\phi dx$  (where $P$ is a hypersurface).

So yours is the integral of f over the hypersurface $g=0$.  If by $g^{-1}(0)$ is meant $g=0$ then

$\int_{g^{-1}(0)}f(r)dx$

is the right half of your equation.