# $n$-dimensional integral of delta function

Tags: integration

As part of an exercise for quantum mechanics I have to solve the following integral:

$$ \int \delta\left( a- \frac{x^2}{b} \right)\; \mathrm{d}^nx =  a^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \cdot b^{\frac{n}{2}} .\tag{1}$$

I do have the solution to the integral, but I can't figure out how to get to it. I know I have to use the following identity:

$$\delta\left( x^2 - a^2 \right) = \frac{1}{2|a|}\left[ \delta \left(x-a  \right) + \delta \left( x+a \right) \right] \tag{2}$$

It would be great if someone could give me some hints.

---

### edit 1:

By using the identity from above I get:
$$\delta\left(a-\frac{x^2}{b}\right) =  \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a}} \left[\delta\left(\sqrt{a}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{b}}\right) + \delta\left(\sqrt{a}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{b}}\right)\right]\tag{3}$$

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: I wasn't sure as the delta function is very common in physics.

Comment: Yes, the Delta function is seen in physics, however, your question is about doing an integral, which makes it not about physics but doing maths. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: Hint: Rewrite in spherical coordinates. There is a factor ${\rm Vol}(S^{n-1})$ missing in eq. (1).

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $a,b>0$. Define for later convenience 
$$f(r)~:=~\frac{r^2}{b}-a.$$
Then OP's integral becomes
$$I~:=~\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \!\mathrm{d}^nx~\delta\left(\frac{x^2}{b}-a\right) 
~\stackrel{\text{Spher. coord.}}{=}~{\rm Vol}(S^{n-1})\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \!\mathrm{d}r~r^{n-1}~\delta(f(r))$$
$$~=~{\rm Vol}(S^{n-1})\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \!\mathrm{d}r~r^{n-1}~\sum_{r_0>0}^{f(r_0)=0}\frac{1}{|f^{\prime}(r)|} \delta(r\!-\!r_0)~\stackrel{r_0=\sqrt{ab}}{=}~{\rm Vol}(S^{n-1})\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \!\mathrm{d}r~r^{n-1}~\frac{b}{2r}\delta(r\!-\!r_0)$$
$$~=~{\rm Vol}(S^{n-1})  \frac{r_0^{n-2}b}{2}
~=~\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}  a^{\frac{n}{2}-1}b^{\frac{n}{2}},$$
where we have used the formula for the volume of an [$n$-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere), and the
substitution rule for [Dirac delta distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276583/11127) & [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/619083/11127) math.SE posts.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the argument of the $\delta$-function to the first order in $x$ around the point where it vanishes.

Comment: I just used the identity stated above on my problem. Is this what you ment by expanding?

Comment: @kaos I meant that it is the way to derive (2) and the case of arbitrary function $f(x)$ under the $\delta$.