# Measuring a curve with Dirac delta function.

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-curves

Formally, if I want to measure the length of a closed curve $f(x,y) = 0$, I presumed I could write:

$$ L = \int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \delta( f(x,y) )\, dx\, dy, $$

but trying this out I don't think this works. What is wrong with this formula?

Edit: Am I missing a measure like a Jacobian or something? How can you prove this?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by "measure a closed curve". You mean arc length?

Comment: yes. Measuring the length of a curve.

Comment: The limits on the integral are all $+\infty$.

Comment: If your curve was a single point, then it's 'length' would be $1$ according to this.

Comment: Let's check what happens for a circle. Let $R$ be the radius. Then we can take $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - R^2,$ so we get
$$
L = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x^2 + y^2 - R^2) \, dx \, dy \\
= \{ \text{ polar coordinates } \} \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \left( \int_0^\infty \delta(r^2 - R^2) \, r \, dr \right) \, d\theta \\
= \{ u = r^2 \} \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \left( \int_0^\infty \delta(u-R^2) \, \frac12 du \right) \, d\theta \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac12 \, d\theta = \pi
$$
@BenedictWilliamJohnIrwin. Wouldn't we get the same result for a single point where $R = 0$?

Comment: @md2perpe That is somewhat perplexing...

Well the content of this question might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619083/dirac-delta-function-of-non-linear-multivariable-arguments

Comment: I believe the real formula for the length of the line would be $\int\int \delta(f(x,y)) \sqrt{ (\partial_x f )^2 + (\partial_y f )^2 } dx dy $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the integral $L := \iint_{\mathbb R^2} \delta(f(x,y)) \, dx \, dy$
to measure the length of the curve $f(x,y) = 0$ we must have $\|\nabla f(x,y)\| = 1$ where $f(x,y) = 0.$ This is related to [the scaling property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry).

So in the case of the circle with center in $(0,0)$ and radius $R,$ we could take $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2R} (x^2+y^2-R^2).$ This would then give
$$
L = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta\left( \frac{1}{2R}(x^2 + y^2 - R^2) \right) \, dx \, dy \\ 
= \{ \text{ polar coordinates } \} \\ 
= \int_0^{2\pi} \left( \int_0^\infty \delta\left( \frac{1}{2R}(r^2 - R^2) \right) \, r \, dr \right) \, d\theta \\ 
= \left\{ u = \frac{1}{2R}r^2 \right\} \\ 
= \int_0^{2\pi} \left( \int_0^\infty \delta\left( u-R/2 \right) \, R \, du \right) \, d\theta \\
 = \int_0^{2\pi} R \, d\theta 
= 2\pi \, R.
$$

Comment: But here you have $|\Delta f| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}/R$.

Comment: Which equals $1$ where $f(x, y) = 0,$ i.e. when $x^2+y^2-R^2 = 0.$

Comment: yes, that's true. I guess it only needs to hold true on the curve itself.