# Properties of delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Consider two arbitrary sets of coordinates $z_0$ and $z$ in some space, mapped via some
$\bar{z} :$=$z_0 \rightarrow z$

I have a function
$$\tag{1}\rho(z)=\int\delta(z-\bar{z}(z_0))\rho_0 (z_0)dz_0$$
this will give me
$$\tag{2}\rho(z)=\rho_0 (\bar{z}^{-1}(z))\frac{\partial z_0}{\partial z}$$
How to obtain equation (2) from equation (1).

Comment: This should be what you are looking for; https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56939/8157

Comment: Also, please use the double dollar and the "\tag" command for display formulas, instead of ------ Click on "edit" to see how I have done.