# Compute the derivative $\partial_t\int_{\{u(t,\cdot) >0\} } 1\, dx$ in the sense of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, distribution-theory

Let $u:\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ be bounded function that solves (in the sense of distributions) an evolution PDE $\partial_t u(t,x)= L(u(t,\cdot))(x)$, where $L$ is some elliptic operator in divergence form.

In a post on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331234/compute-partial-t-int-ut-cdot-0-1-dx-in-the-sense-of-distributi), a calculation was made regarding the time derivative $$\partial_t\int_{\{u(t,\cdot) >0\} } 1\,  dx$$ in the following way:

> $$\partial_t\int_{\{u(t,\cdot) >0\} } 1\,  dx= ∫_\Omega \delta[u(t,x)]\partial_t u(t,x)\,dx=\int_{S(t)}\frac{\partial_t u(t,x)}{|\nabla_x u(t,x)|}d\sigma(x).$$

- How can one rewrite this calculation emphasizing the fact that we are doing a derivative in the sense of distributions, i.e. 
  $$\langle \partial_t T, \phi\rangle = -\langle T, \partial_t\phi \rangle $$
  where $T$ is the distribution associated with $\int_{\{u(t,\cdot) >0\} } 1\,  dx$?
- And how can we use the fact that $u$ solves the PDE above in the final formula?

Comment: I learned this kind of computations in the notes of Sergiu Klainerman: https://web.math.princeton.edu/~seri/homepage/courses/Analysis2011.pdf
(See how he proves the divergence theorem, pag. 73)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for the reference. In this specific problem, it is the integral that confuses me.

Comment: [This post is very much related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56939/8157).

Comment: The difficulty is to define $ d\sigma(x)$, it is quite obvious for a given $u$ it exists, but obtaining a [simple expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_content) for any $u$ isn't

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you. But unfortunately, I'm not able to derive an answer to this question from it. How can it be done?

Comment: $v(x) = u(t,x)$ then $\delta(v(x)) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1_{v(x) \in [-h,+h]}}{2h}$.

Let $S = \{ x, v(x)=0\}$. If $v$ is smooth and $\nabla v(x_0)$ never vanishes for $x_0\in S$ then $S$ is a hypersurface, locally it is an hyperplane and $\nabla v(x)$ is constant, so it suffices to check the case $v(x) = \nabla v(x_0) . (x-x_0)$ for which $\int_{\Bbb{R}^N} \delta(v(x)) \phi(x)d^N x = \int_S\frac{\phi(x)}{\|\nabla v(x)\|_2}d\sigma_S(x)$ where $\sigma_S$ is the Minkowski content measure of $S$. From there it suffices to extend from test functions $\phi$ to distributions.

Comment: @reuns Could you expand your comment in an answer, please?

Comment: A thought, if supp $\phi=U$, $$-(\partial_tT,\phi)=\int_U\partial_t \phi(t)\int_{u(x,t)>0}dxdt =\int_{\{(x,t) : u(x,t)>0, \ t\in U \}}\nabla_{x_1,\dots,x_N,t}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0\\ \vdots\\0\\ \phi(t)\end{bmatrix} dxdt $$ lets you use Gauss's theorem.
I believe
$$\partial \{(x,t) : u(x,t)>0, \ t\in U \} \\=  \{(x,t) : u(x,t)=0, \ t\in U \}\cup  \{(x,t) : u(x,t)>0, \ t\in \partial U \}.$$ On the set $ \{(x,t) : u(x,t)>0, \ t\in \partial U \}$, there is no contribution since $U$ is the support of $\phi$. So someone who can integrate on the level set $\{u(x,t)=0\}$ (not me) can finish.