# Manifold re-expressed as a generalized distribution function.

Tags: functions, distribution-theory, integral-domain

I recently rediscovered generalized functions and distributions as generalized functions.

I found out many integrals "over the charge distribution" can instead be recast as integrals over all space and replace a density function with a density distribution. For example: The surface area of a sphere. Normally we begin computing the area of the sphere by choosing our coordinates. If we choose the $r\theta\phi$ coordinates, then we may write (for a sphere of radius R centered on the origin):

$$
S 
= 
\iint\ dA
=
\int_{\theta=0}^\pi
\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}R^2\sin\theta\ d\theta d\phi
=
4\pi R^2
$$

In terms of a distribution, we may write that the distribution of the sphere is $\rho=\delta(r-R)$. Now we may write:

$$
S=\iiint \rho\ dV
=\int_{r=0}^{\infty}
\int_{\theta=0}^\pi
\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}
\delta(r-R) r^2\sin\theta\ d\theta d\phi
$$

Which also give the correct result of $S=4\pi R^2$ since $\int_{r=0}^\infty r^2\delta(r-R)dr=R^2$.

I also noted that if we move back to $xyz$ coordinates, we have $\rho=\delta(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-R)$. We can employ [the expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) $\delta(g(\alpha))=\sum_i \frac{\delta(\alpha-\beta_i)}{\left|g'(\beta_i)\right|}$ where each of the $\beta_i$ are roots of $g(\alpha)$. With respect to $x$, the solutions to $g(x)=0$, where  $g(x)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-R$, are given by $\beta_{\pm}=\pm\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}$. The derivative can be evaluated as follows: $g'(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$. So $g'_+(\beta_+)=\frac{\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}}{R}$ and $g'_-(\beta_-)=\frac{-\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}}{R}$. This gives us:

$$
S=\iiint\ \rho\ dV=\iiint \delta\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-R\right)\ dxdydz\\
=\iiint\ \frac{\delta(x-\beta_+)}{|g'(\beta_+)|}+\frac{\delta(x-\beta_-)}{|g'(\beta_-)|}\ dxdydz\\
=\iiint\ 
\frac{R\delta(x-\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2})}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}}
+
\frac{R\delta(x+\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2})}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}}\ dxdydz\\
=\iiint\ 
\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}}
\left[
\delta(x-\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2})+\delta(x+\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2})
\right] dxdydz\\
$$

It would seem to be the case that $\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2})dx=1$ and $\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x+\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2})dx=1$ so that the above integral becomes:

$$
S=\iint\ 
\frac{2R}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}}dydz
$$

This does not converge according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B2R%2CSqrt%5BPower%5BR%2C2%5D-Power%5By%2C2%5D-Power%5Bz%2C2%5D%5D%5D%2C%7By%2C-%E2%88%9E%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%2C%7Bz%2C-%E2%88%9E%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) as long as the bounds are unaffected. Thus clearly there is something wrong with this derivation. I hypothesize there is some other step involved with solving for the roots or the domain of integration on the yz coordinates is otherwise affected. Perhaps the integrals in $x$ on the delta functions do not sum to 2.

---

Begining from

$$
S=
\iiint\ \frac{\delta(x-\beta_+)}{|{\bf \nabla}g(\beta_+)|}+\frac{\delta(x-\beta_-)}{|{\bf \nabla} g(\beta_-)|}\ dxdydz\\
$$

Here ${\bf \nabla} g = {\bf \hat{r}}$, so $|\nabla g|=1$, and thus we have for S:

$$
S=
\iiint
\delta(x-\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2})+\delta(x+\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2})
\ dxdydz
$$

---

Additional question:

Is there a general method for transforming between integrating over some specified region, such as a curve or surface, to integrating over all space and expressing the domain of integration in terms of appropriate distribution functions?

Comment: OK, to be honest I didn't read all that. However I think I understand where you are slipping. That Dirac formula which you call "the expansion" is only valid in 1d. In higher dimension, [use this instead](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56939/8157)

Comment: Oh, and you inadvertently answered my second question too. It's the method is called a simple layer integral.

Comment: Great! Yes, simple layer integral sounds like a very relevant keyword here.