# Integral of Dirac[t] delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

When calculating $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\delta\big(g(x)\big)\, \mathrm dx$$ one can use the fact that $$\delta\big( g(x) \big) = \sum_i\dfrac {\delta(x-x_i)}{\left|g'(x_i)\right|}$$ where $g(x_i)=0$ to determine $I$.

However, what happens in the case where we're not integrating over the whole real line, but instead one (or multiple) such $x_i$s happen to be integration bounds -- e.g. $$\int_0^1 \delta(x^2-x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Or, more broadly, what is $$\int_0^\infty \delta(x)\, \mathrm dx$$?

Comment: Recall that distributions are "really" linear functionals on test functions.  So write these things you want to know in that form.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is not a function.   Moreover, one does not integrate a distribution.  So there is no associated interval.  And the symbol $\int_0^\infty \delta(x)\,dx=\langle H, \delta\rangle$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function, has no meaning.

Comment: @MarkViola I would say that we can give a precise meaning to such integrals by interpreting/defining them as limits.

Comment: @Filippo They are not integrals.  And as I wrote, there is NO meaning to $\langle \delta,H\rangle$.  If one wishes, one can define the symbol $\int_a^b \delta(x-c)\phi(x)\,dx$ as the functional $\langle \delta_c,\xi_{[a,b]}\phi\rangle$ PROVIDED that $c\ne a$ and $c\ne b$.

Comment: I thought $\cases{\delta(x)=0,x\ne0\\\delta(x)=\infty,x=0}$. Therefore, the $\delta(x)$ is many to one and a function. Also, the interval that the dirac delta function is $\infty$ is $[0,0]$ giving no area under the interval. So,$\int_0^\infty\delta(x)dx=0$
Why does this method fail?

Comment: @TymaGaidash what you wrote is precisely a proof that the function you wrote doesn’t satisfy the most important property we want for the Dirac delta. So the definition as a function is ‘wrong’.

Comment: There is no meaning to $\int_0^\infty \delta$ ... see e.g. this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427947/what-is-the-value-of-the-integral-int-inftya-deltax-a-dx-and-relate in your case with $a=0$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, the integrals
$\newcommand\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \delta(x)\dif x
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \delta(x^2-x)\dif x
\end{equation}
are not defined in the context of distribution theory. Here is one way to justify this: Let $\delta_\epsilon$ be a [nascent dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function), then the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^\infty \delta_\epsilon(x)\dif x
\end{equation}
is not independent of the chosen sequence and may even not exist ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4507909/572841) is the proof).

That being said, one may still assign a value to these integrals: As explained in [Mathematics for Physicists](https://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/physics/mathematical-methods/mathematics-physicists-introductory-concepts-and-methods?format=HB) we can define such integrals by restricting ourselves to "appropriate" representations of the $\delta$-function, e.g. the Gaussian representation
\begin{equation}
\delta_\epsilon(x)=\frac{\exp(-x^2/\epsilon^2)}{\epsilon\sqrt\pi}
\end{equation}
or the Lorentzian representation:
\begin{equation}
\delta_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}
\end{equation}
Then we obtain the following results:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^\infty \delta_\epsilon(x)\dif x=\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^\infty \delta_\epsilon(x^2-x)\dif x=1
\end{equation}

### Sketch of the proof

More generally, we can consider integrals of the form
\begin{equation}
\int_A\delta(g(x))\dif x:=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_A\delta_\epsilon(g(x))\dif x
\end{equation}
To be precise, we consider the following setting: $g$ is defined on an open set $D\subset\mathbb R$ and $A\subset D$ such that $g$ has finitely many zeros
$$x_1<\ldots<x_n$$ in $A$. $A$ is not necessarely open. Furthermore, we assume that $g$ is a diffeomorphism on a neighbourhood of each zero. Now let $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ be a list of disjoint subsets in $A$ which are open w.r.t. to the relative topology and with $x_i\in U_i$. Then:
\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon:\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_A\delta_\epsilon(g(x))\dif x=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\bigcup_i U_i}\delta_\epsilon(g(x))\dif x+\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{A\setminus\bigcup_i U_i}\delta_\epsilon(g(x))\dif x\\=\sum_i\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{U_i}\delta_\epsilon(g(x))\dif x+\underbrace{\int_{A\setminus\bigcup_i U_i}\underbrace{\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\delta_\epsilon(g(x))}_{=0}\dif x}_{=0}\\=\sum_i\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{g(U_i)}\frac{\delta(y)}{|(g'\circ g^{-1})(y)|}\dif y=\sum_i\frac{c_i}{|g'(x_i)|}
\end{align}
with $c_i=1$ if $g(x_i)$ is an inner point of $g(U_i)$ which is equivalent to $x_i$ being an inner point of $D$ since $g|_{U_i}$ is a diffeo (I am not 100% sure regarding the equivalence) and $c_i=1/2$ otherwise (i.e. if $x_i$ is a boundary point of $U_i$).

Not let us apply the result above to your example: In our case, we choose some $0<\epsilon<1/2$ such that $g(x)=x^2-x$ is a diffeo on $[0,\epsilon]$ and on $[1-\epsilon,1]$. Note that $g(\epsilon)=\epsilon^2-\epsilon<0$ and $g(1-\epsilon)=-\epsilon(1-\epsilon)<0$ and we obtain:
\begin{align}
\forall\epsilon:\int_0^1 \delta_\epsilon(x^2-x)\dif x=\int_0^\epsilon \delta_\epsilon(g(x))\dif x+\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \delta_\epsilon(g(x))\dif x\\=\int_{\epsilon^2-\epsilon}^0 \frac{\delta_\epsilon(y)}{|(g'\circ g^{-1})(y)|}\dif y+\int_{-\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}^0 \frac{\delta_\epsilon(y)}{|(g'\circ g^{-1})(y)|}\dif y
\end{align}
and thus:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^1 \delta_\epsilon(x^2-x)\dif x=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{|g'(0)|}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{|g'(1)|}=1
\end{equation}

Comment: This is not correct.  There are an infinite number of nascent Dirac Deltas and NOT ALL will  lead to the same result for the case in which $H$ is used as a test funtion.  $H$ is not continuous and does not qualify.

Comment: There are nine (9) references to "nascent" Dirac Deltas in [THIS ARTICLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).   And a simple internet search, using Google for example, will lead you to a host of other references.  The key is that there are many functions commonly used as nascent Deltas.  But not all of these lead to the same result with non-test functions (e.g., H).  I would suggest that you review the theroy of distributions.

Comment: It MUST hold for all nascent Deltas.  Else, it fails.  And it does fail.  Please read about the theory of distributions.

Comment: The headline of the question references the Dirac Delta.  Your answer does not address this.  The 3 net downvotes might alert you that you might just be on the wrong side of an argument.

Comment: @MarkViola "Your answer does not address this" - I have further edited my question to address **why** the integrals are undefined (I have provided a link with examples of nascent dirac deltas where the limits do not exist or have different values). But I have the impression that we have reached the point where other users are heavily influenced by the downvotes and the votes are not objective any more.

Comment: I think this answer gives a useful discussion of issues relevant to the question. After all, the reason L. Schwartz won a Fields Medal was for giving a good foundation for exactly these sorts of computations and heuristics, which pre-existed any distribution theory (or Sobolev spaces, also).

Comment: @paulgarrett Thank you, your comment is much appreciated :)

Answer (score -4):

An integral of the type $\int _0 ^1 \delta(x^2-x)dx$ may appear confusing at first, but can be understood by choosing a suitable representation of the Dirac delta function. The block-form is the simplest (and often the best):

$\delta_\epsilon (y) = 1/(2\epsilon) \qquad$ if $\qquad -\epsilon < y < \epsilon \qquad and \qquad =0 \qquad $ otherwise

Application of this representation to the integral above means finding the values of $x$ where the argument is larger than $-\epsilon$. Up to linear order in $\epsilon$ this results in the two regions $0 < x < \epsilon$ and $1-\epsilon < x < 1$. The integral therefore simplifies to

$$\int _0 ^\epsilon 1/(2\epsilon) dx + \int _{1-\epsilon} ^1 1/(2\epsilon)dx = 1/2 + 1/2 = 1$$

EDIT: Here is a more formal way of evaluating the intgral. First we split the intgration interval into two regions: $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2, 1)$. Now introduce the new variable $y = x^2-x$. This is equivalent to $x = 1/2 + \sqrt{y + 1/4}$ or $x = 1/2 - \sqrt{y + 1/4}$. The minus sign corresponds to the first interval, the plus to the second. Differentiation with respect to $y$ yields the relation between $dx$ and $dy$. Substitution into the original expression gives:

$$\int_{0}^{-1/4}(-1/2)/\sqrt{y+1/4} \ \delta(y)dy + \int_{-1/4}^{0}(1/2)/\sqrt{y+1/4} \ \delta(y)dy$$

This is a trivial integral that reduces to $1/2 + 1/2 = 1$. So the "loose" method and the "formal" method lead to the same result. Note that if the original intgral contained a smooth test function $f(x)$, the result with both methods would be: $(f(0)+f(1))/2$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138290/discussion-on-answer-by-m-wind-integral-of-diract-delta-function).