# Weak derivative, constants infront of Dirac-delta

Tags: dirac-delta, weak-derivatives

I'm currently taking a PDE course, and would like some help with understanding weak derivatives.

My question is: when computing weak derivative and getting a result like $f'=-2\delta_1 + 4\delta_2 + g$, what difference does the constants infront of Dirac-delta do? When sketching the weak derivative we only show Dirac-delta as an arrow, so I do not really understand what difference the constants makes in this case.

Comment: A sensible way to distinguish is to draw $\delta$ as an arrow of height $1$ and $2\delta$ as an arrow of height $2$, for example.

Comment: I understand. But it seems like constants with Dirac-delta must have another purpose later on? Because, so far, Dirac-delta just is "what it is", and not something that we do actual calculations with.

Comment: It definitely does have a purpose! $\delta$ is, loosely, "an object such that when you integrate $\delta(x) f(x)\,\,\mathrm dx$ you get $f(0)$". You can be more formal or less formal about this. There is much discussion of this on this site eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56684/473276) - and I'd expect this to have come up/come up soon in your course, or to have come up in a prerequisite course. Then $2\delta$ is "an object such that when you integrate $2\delta(x) f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ you get $2f(0)$."

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! Then it will probably come up later in the course, and I know that it does make a difference.